# Limitations of sklearn Truncated SVD (LSA) Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I have the following scenario: I must analyze a big collection of text documents (around 3,000) and perform some clustering technic to gain some insight over it. To extract features I'm using tf-idf, but it yields more than 20,000 features which makes it difficult to achieve good results with clustering. So I started using LSA to reduce the dimensionality and improve the results. Here is a sample code using sci-kit learn's implementations:

```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=categories, 
                              shuffle=True, random_state=42)
data = dataset.data
labels = dataset.target

vectorizer =TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,1), 
                             min_df=2, max_df=0.5, strip_accents='unicode',
                             smooth_idf=1, sublinear_tf=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=k)
normalizer = Normalizer(copy=False)
lsa = make_pipeline(svd, normalizer)

X = lsa.fit_transform(X)

# clustering over X
```

As I described above, I have more the 20,000 features and I wish I could reduce to half, for example, however if I use such big values for `n_components`, the `lsa.fit_transform(X)` returns exactly `n_components = n_documents`. The only values that work as expected are values bellow the number of documents. Is this something I'm missing from the theory or the implementation has this limitation? As far as I know from the theory of the LSA technic, the number of components to reduce the dimensionality to is unbounded and intuitively, I imagine that using a number of components that is closer to the number of features is better that use less than a fourth of it, because it would require less concepts to be grouped in more high level concepts. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I only know this for principle component analysis for sure, but I guess it works similar for LSA and nobody else answered this question, so I'll try. Imagine that you have 2 documents and 3 features, resulting in a 3-dimensional coordinate system with two datapoints. These two datapoints can be connected with a straight line, and therefore only need a two-dimensional coordinate system to be described.

Accordingly, two principle components are going to be enough to explain all the variance in the data. If you have higher dimensions, the number of documents you have will determine how many dimensions you need to describe your data.

Comment: It's been a while since I studied this in school and since the question remained unanswered I settled with this alleged limitation of sklearn for the sake of completing the assignment, but a far as I remember, LSA will try to group the terms in higher level terms that will describe you documents in a way that it will reduce the feature space, similarly to PCA, but I don't remember hearing about a limit for the number of high level concepts beeing set on the number of documents/data points. I'd love to hear from someone who really understand LSA

Comment: Not that I'm saying that you don't understand it :)

Comment: Yeah, that's alright. I'm also rather curious if someone comes up with a better/different solution